# $(pgrep -f) behaviour changes within a script depending on the shebang

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, pgrep

When I run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
$(pgrep -u ubuntu -f ${1} > /dev/null)
echo "CURRENT_STATUS="${?}
```

with:

```
./my_script.sh top
```

when `top` is not running, it returns:

```
CURRENT_STATUS=0
```

which is odd, as I would expect a `1` exit status from `pgrep`.
When I remove the shebang from the script it works as expected.

Could someone help me understand what's going on here?

This is on an Ubuntu 22.4.1 system.
Also note that the `$(...)` doesn't change the results.

I have noticed that `pgrep` seems to be matching against itself and that's why it gives a 0 result no matter what process name I feed it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us your operating system. Why are you using `$()` when all you want is to run a command, is that on purpose?

Comment: @terdon - I've edited. Thanks.

Comment: @ilkkachu this is run from within a bash shell

Comment: The `$()` won't change the result, it's just weird and pointless there so I asked in case there were other parts of the script you're not showing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the hashbang, the kernel runs the named interpreter passing it the script file name and the arguments you give, i.e. the command line is `/bin/bash ./my_script.sh top`, and that shows in the process listing with e.g. `ps`, and similarly `pgrep` finds it. It matches the keyword `top`, after all.

Without the hashbang, the kernel-level system call fails, and Bash runs the script itself, internally, and the arguments don't show in the process listing. (The shells do that, some way or another. IIRC it's a POSIX requirement that non-executable files be run through the shell if possible.)

It's easier to test with e.g. these two:

```
bash$ cat wait.sh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 50

bash$ cat wait2.sh
sleep 50

bash$ ./wait.sh & ./wait2.sh & ps uax |grep wait
ilkkachu  9029  0.0  0.0  15368  3060 pts/21   S    20:01   0:00 /bin/bash ./wait.sh
ilkkachu  9032  0.0  0.0  16964   968 pts/21   S+   20:01   0:00 grep wait
```

the one without the hashbang doesn't show up.

I think `pgrep` is smart enough not to find itself, but to help it not find the script, you could use a pattern like `'[t]op'`, which matches `top`, but not itself. With `./my_script.sh '[t]op'`, the difference disappears.

The command substitution there is useless, though, just drop it and run `pgrep` directly.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's an incredibly helpful and concisely explained insight into how scripts are executed.

Comment: I've gone for this edit to the script which seems to work and I think is correct by theory too. What do you think?
    #!/bin/bash;
    pgrep -ai -u ubuntu -f ${1} | grep -v $0;
    echo "CURRENT_STATUS="${?}

Comment: @ozpac, looks like it might work. Maybe I'd go with `pgrep -i -f "$1" | grep -vxF "$$"`, i.e. looking at the process id of the script instead of the name (to remove any possible name clash, which would likely be rare but really hard to debug). `grep -x` to look at the whole line, so as not to match 1234 in 12345. Also, quote the expansions just for the sake of a good habit :)

Comment: Good thinking @ikkachu. Thank you again for your help - it's really appreciated.